# Iluminate database problem with schema builder hasTable method

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate

I've got a legacy codebase making use of the illuminate database components. 
From the documentation its apparent I should be able to detect presence of a table in the underlying database using the Schema component.

This is my attempt

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder as SchemaBuilder;

$schema = new SchemaBuilder(Database::getFactory()->getConnection());
```

I then run some tests on this.

```
print_r(get_class_methods($schema));

// outputs 

Array ( [0] => __construct [1] => hasTable [2] => hasColumn [3] => getColumnListing [4] => table [5] => create [6] => drop [7] => dropIfExists [8] => rename [9] => getConnection [10] => setConnection [11] => blueprintResolver )
```

So seems happy enough.

Then.

```
$schema->hasTable('users');
```

and I get the following error

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function compileTableExists() on null in
```

Comment: It seems like `Database::getFactory()->getConnection()->getSchemaGrammar()` returns `null`.

Comment: What about ```Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::connection('mysql')->hasTable('users');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out in the end.

```php
$schema_builder = $capsule->connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
if($schema_builder->hasTable('users'))
    echo 'table found';
else
    echo 'table not found';
```